# MySQL ordering by value from two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

In one table row, I have a columns product_price. If product has lower price (discount),the discount_price column is set in sql result as alias. If product is no discounted (no lower price) this colum discount_price is null.

What i want is order this set and sort by values from product_price (if discount_price is null) and discount_price.

For example

```
 
----------------------------------------
ID    product_price   discount_price
----------------------------------------
1        4800            NULL
2        13000           4400
3        3300            NULL
4        10500           9600
5        1600            NULL
```

I want to get this result when ordering descend: (If discount_price is null, check value in product_price, if discount_price is not_null check value in discout_price)

```
----------------------------------------
ID    product_price   discount_price
----------------------------------------
4        10500           9600
1        4800            NULL
2        13000           4400
3        3300            NULL
5        1600            NULL
```

Comment: Try if it is possible to `ORDER BY IFNULL(discount_price, product_price)` I'm nt sure if something like that is possible , but it's worth a try

Comment: your wished result have no meaning and they are not ordered as you said.

Comment: Have you tried constructing a query yet?

Comment: Also you can use the `COALESCE` function, which picks the first non-null value: `ORDER BY COALESCE(discount_price, product_price)` _(It all comes down to which you find more readable: IF, IFNULL, CASE, COALESCE)_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
ORDER BY IFNULL(discount_price, product_price);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 SELECT * FROM table1
 ORDER BY CASE WHEN discount_price IS NULL     then PRODUCT_PRICE
               WHEN discount_price IS NOT NULL then discount_price 
     END DESC
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/80df9/1)

Comment: Well that is basically what `IFNULL` does... have you tried the `IFNULL`-Approach? The code would be much cleaner and shorter then. I guess faster as well